# Set up a transparent proxy with a forwarded port on mac OS X

Tags: ssh, proxy, squid

I want to set up a transparent proxy on mac, I searched and ended up using squid(squidMan in my case for mac) for that. Now I have forwarded my traffic over a port using ssh like this:

```
ssh root@ip -L 0.0.0.0:5145:127.0.0.1:5145 -N -C
```

The port is again forwarded in the SSHed server using `ssh root@another-ip -D 5145`

Now what I want to do is to set up a transparent proxy with squid, that proxies all traffic through this 5145 port. I want to proxy traffic in another device in the same subnet from this port. I'm using manual http-proxy in the WI-FI setting of my android phone.
I have tested setting the http-proxy port to 5145 but it didn't work. Then I tested another random port but it didn't work either. I'm not exactly sure that the squid itself is using the 5145 proxy.

Can anybody shed a light on how it is supposed to work?